# Opening a file using ScriptingBridge

Tags: objective-c, applescript, photoshop, scripting-bridge

I have an AppleScript that I am trying to convert to ScriptingBridge. Since my application is a C++/Obj-C application, ScriptingBridge is much easier to use and quite a bit faster (not to mention I hate dynamically building AppleScripts).

The AppleScript sends a message to Photoshop to open a file. The file parameter is sent as an `alias`, but ScriptingBridge imports the parameter as an `id`. I don't know what Obj-C object I should pass in?

I've tried passing an NSURL and an NSString (probably incorrectly :-P), but to no avail. Any suggestions on what I should be passing for the file alias?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you can't open documents in Photoshop with Scripting Bridge.

Apple's docs really spell it out like it is. All classes must have a container, which is a mutable array, that they need to be added to before they can be acted upon, as shown in the generated header...

```
@interface photoshopCS4Application : SBApplication

- (SBElementArray *) documents;
- (SBElementArray *) fonts;
- (SBElementArray *) notifiers;
```

... and that is the complete list of top-level containers available to us. The `open` command *requires* a `photoshopCS4OpenOptions` to be generated and populated. Because the API doesn't expose the array to store the newly created photoshopCS4OpenOptions object, we can't use a newly created `photoshopCS4OpenOptions` object. Therefore we can't make a target document and by extensions can't use the `open` command in Scripting Bridge. The same can be said of all the commands that require some kind of options object.

The only workaround that I have sorted out is to either open a document with native Applescript called from Cocoa or objc-appscript, and then parse the `documents` array looking for the one just opened. It's not ideal, but then neither is Scripting Bridge because it requires application developers write their scripting APIs in a very specific way that is not native to the OSA framework.

Answer (score 1):

If your program is such that opening a Photoshop document can be executed outside your AppleScript script/Scripting Bridge code, Cocoa provides a method to open files with a specific application:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile:@"/Users/bavarious/Desktop/test.psd" withApplication:@"Adobe Photoshop CS4"];
```

or, if you want to use the default application that handles that file type, you can drop the application name altogether:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile:@"/Users/bavarious/Desktop/test.psd"];
```

Comment: Cool, that's another, arguably better, way than I proposed. The caveat is that the OP still has to go through the `documents` array to look for the one that was just opened, if opened successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Consider Appscript.  http://appscript.sourceforge.net/

Here's the code using that:

APApplication *adobePhotoshopCs4 = [APApplication applicationWithName: @"Adobe Photoshop CS4"];
id result = [[adobePhotoshopCs4 open_] send];

(Note, I'm not a Cocoa programmer - I mainly use Appscript with Python but Appscript comes with ASTranslate which translates Applescript into Python, Ruby or Obj-C and that's the output - but I've found there are subtle mistakes in the past sometimes with the translator)